# JBoss behind Apache redirecting to localhost

Tags: jboss, apache-2.2

I know this is in *Apache & JBoss Configuration 101* but I just can't work it out.

I am configuring Apache 2.2.3 to use `mod_proxy_http` to forward requests to JBoss 5.1.0 GA. The idea being that there will be multiple JBoss instances fronted by a single Apache.

Both JBoss and Apache are on the same physical box.

I have a configuration file in `conf.d` which reads as follows:

```
Listen 8087
<VirtualHost *:8087>
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /admin-console http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console
    ProxyPassReverse /admin-console http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console

    <Location /admin-console>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

And I have JBoss listening on port 8080 bound to 127.0.0.1.

If I visit http://myServer:8087/admin-console I get the login prompt but the images are missing. If I then enter the username and password the browser gets redirected to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console/login.seam
```

So, obviously JBoss is sending URLs for images/CSS/etc and the `login.seam` page which are localhost.

How do I change this? Is it a configuration in Apache, or should I change JBoss somewhere? If this is a change in JBoss, I would like it to be a global change as we will be installing many apps on each JBoss instance. Crucially I don't want JBoss to bind to the server's hostname so that it can be accessed directly at http://myServer:8080/admin-console.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
    <Location /admin-console>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console
    </Location>
```

I needed to put the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives inside the Location directive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting trailing slashes on the URLs?

eg

```
ProxyPass /admin-console/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console/
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can run like ip address of you box run.sh -b 192.168.1.100 then check again.

Comment: That doesn't work because it makes JBoss visible @ 192.168.1.100:8080 and I don't want that.